# pass data from view to controller in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In view I have DropDownList that when some item is selected that calls to function from the controller,

I'm trying to **pass parameter** to function in the controller from the view.

All I have is that I can call from index.html to function from Homecontroller.cs without parameter, all I need now is to pass some string.

my code for now:

```
    **Index.cshtml:**

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("nMap", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Get",                                              
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name = "map", @class = "form-control", onchange = "CallChangefunc()" })
}     
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
   function CallChangefunc() {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("nMap", "Home")';
   }
</script>
```

**HomVM:**

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Files { get; set; }
    public string SelectedFileName { get; internal set; }
    public List<string> DynamicAlgorithems { get; set; }
}
```

**Homecontroller.cs:**

```
.
.
.
 [ActionName("nMap")]
 public ActionResult NMap()
 {

      //some code
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

> all I need is something like:

Index.cshtml:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name = "map", @class = "form-control", onchange = "CallChangefunc("+someStringParam+")" })
```

Homecontroller.cs

```
[ActionName("nMap")]
public ActionResult NMap(string someStringParam)
{
 //do something with the param
}
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[ActionName("nMap")]
public ActionResult NMap(string someStringParam)
{
 //do something with the param
}
```

TO

```
[ActionName("nMap"),HttpGet]
public ActionResult NMap(SelectListItem SelectedFileName)
{
 //do something with the param
}
```

MVC uses naming conventions to line up parameter mappings.

Also

Change

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name     = "map", @class = "form-control", onchange = "CallChangefunc()" }
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name     = "map", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
```

And get rid of the JavaScript altogether.

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Files { get; set; }
    public string SelectedFileName { get; internal set; }
    public List<string> DynamicAlgorithems { get; set; }
}
```

Should be

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Files { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem SelectedFileName { get; internal set; }
    public List<string> DynamicAlgorithems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: when I choose some item it calls the fuction but it says that `SelectedFileName` is null, can you see why?

Comment: Sorry I missed the VM.FIles was not a string type. See updates.

Comment: Also you could change the method parameter to be type HomeVM and get the SelectedListItem from the VM internals but its not necessary here.

Comment: `SelectedFileName.Value` is  empty string, can you see why?